# Broken iPhone battery no fire

Tags: ions

I work on electrical and Electronics quite often and working on a iPhone the other day with a dead battery,I ruptured it open trying to remove the glue I smelled a funny smell like nail polish remover but no fire or sparks it was completely dead I heard they can release hydrofluric acid but when only when they ignite I been venting the room last few days and removed the phone imidiatly after I ruptured it, is there any danger?

Comment: How is this "medical"? I find it a bit stupid to deny an answer to people who ask "should I suspect that I'm in danger?".

Answer (score 2):

The danger from broken lithium ion batteries is primarily their fire risk not their chemical contents. Broken batteries where short circuits occur can generate enough heat to cause the battery to catch fire and this fire will be vigorous as the batteries contain metallic lithium which is fairly flammable in air and will also react vigorously with water.

Some of the electrolytes in the batteries contain non-coordinating lithium salts like $\ce {LiPF6}$ this is presumably where the rumour that they can leak HF came from but this is very unlikely as they are very unreactive compounds. If the battery burns vigorously the smoke might, possibly, contain some HF but this will be the least of your worries if the device is on fire.

Damaged batteries should be disposed of carefully according to standard safety procedures, but, if it isn't already on fire, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: And the nail polish remover smell comes from the electrolyte solvent, typically carbonates or ethers. (Ethylencarbonat, Propylencarbonat, Dimethylcarbonat, Diethylcarbonat oder 1,2-Dimethoxyethan, just cp from de:wp)

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I am know how electrical and electronics works but was unaware of what batteries contained chemically, When we were in school they always told us never to rupture one because the fumes are highly toxic so I have always been very careful. Finally I slipped with a plastic spuger and ruptured one and took the phone outside imidiatly thank god it didn’t go off but was worried about the fumes and even more worried about the hf released but apprently that’s only if they ignite, I figured I would ask a chemist who would know the composition of something a lot better then i